# CSS Slideshow Video Gallery

Tags: html, css, slideshow, video-gallery

Does anyone know how to make a slideshow video gallery? I've been searching for this but all I could find was slideshow image galleries. If anyone knows anything to refer to for this can you please tell me?

This is how I want to make a video gallery in CSS
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the snap scroll property of CSS to make this kind of Effect.

here are some useful links to learn.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Scroll_Snap

https://css-tricks.com/practical-css-scroll-snapping/

or you can use : `scroll-direction: horizontal;`

https://css-tricks.com/pure-css-horizontal-scrolling/

Or with some tricks and animation you can achieve it like this

https://codepen.io/Schepp/pen/WNbQByE

and last part which is to use videos that is quite easy, just replace the image or text with Video tags or youtube video iframe.

That's it...

Comment: Thank you for these sources!

Comment: Hi Nasheetat, if this helped pls mark this as right answer or you need anything else, pls let me know

Answer (score 0):

If you were able to make an image gallery, then you can simply change the image tags in the code `<img src="file.png"/>` to video tags.

For eample: 
`<video width="300" height="250" controls>`
`<source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">`
`</video>`